# Find row number of a row

Tags: r

I saw several answers for finding the row number of a specific value, how do I find the row number for a specific set of values?
eg, dat is a 3x2 data frame, with values(1,2,3,4,5,6)
I need to find the row number of c(3,4).
any function such that function(dat, c(3,4)) outputs 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` with `which`.  Loop through the column of 'dat', use `%in%` to get a `list` of logical `vector`, `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` with `&` and return the position by wrapping with `which`

```
which(Reduce(`&`, lapply(dat, `%in%`, 3:4)))
#[1] 2
```

It can be wrapped in a function

```
fnRindex <- function(data, vals) {
        which(Reduce(`&`, lapply(data, `%in%`, vals)))
}

fnRindex(dat, 3:4)
```

---

Or another option is with `rowSums` on the `sapply` output

```
which(rowSums(sapply(dat, `%in%`, 3:4))==2)
```

#### data

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

Comment: dat$col is specifying which column to search right? What I'm looking for a is a combination of values

Comment: @AnilVignesh  Can you please check the updated code